# what is the equivalent rewrite rule in nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite

I was having this rewrite rule in Apache2

```
RewriteRule country/usa[/]*$            /en/country/united-states [L,R=301,NC]
```

I have tried to build an equivalent rewrite rule in nginx like this

```
server {
rewrite ^country/usa[/]*$     /en/country/united-states last;
#the remaining of the virtual host
}
```

but this didn't work :( any idea of how to do this?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to the code below should do the work:

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/country/usa$ /en/country/united-states permanent;
}
```

This will redirect only `/country/usa` and `/country/usa/` with a `301 Moved Permanently` status. The other way option is

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/country/usa([/])?(.*)$ /en/country/united-states/$2 permanent;
}
```

which will redirect everything after and including `/country/usa` to the new location. 
For example `/country/usa/testing` will go to `/en/country/united-states/testing`.

Comment: According to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite  "context: server, location, if"

Comment: Yeah.. It appears you're right. Answer was updated.

Answer (score 1):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

<strike>> redirect — returns a temporary redirect with the code 302; used if a replacement string does not start with “http://” or “https://”;</strike>

> permanent — returns a permanent redirect with the code 301.

Comment: I think he should be using `permanent` in this case because in apache `R=301` means `Redirect=Code`. The code he has posted would generate HTTP status code 301 (Moved permanently). http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: @tftd, ough-yeah, for 301 — permanent, sorry.